# Extent of city-building possible in 10 years with access to near current resources?

Tags: post-apocalypse

The setting is Colorado in the USA, duh, where after a zombie apocalypse a local power is emerging.

It's a city-state sort of thing.

Now with the apocalypse overseas travel and imports are not a thing.

So they have to relay on ingenuity and locally available resources.
This of course includes skilled workers and engineers, but of course they are still limited.

**So how much can they do with these limitations in mind?**

Their purpose is to create a self sufficient, as much as possible, mega city where people rarely need to leave.

Current population is reaching a million, after the apocalypse by a decade, but the city also needs to have room for further expansion as it becomes the capital of the new power.

Comment: Does it control enough farmland to feed the city?

Comment: Obviously. 
The power behind the whole state is a local land owning family of farmers.
That's how the whole thing started. 
They just had farmlands which produced enough food for a lot of people, they had guns and numbers...etc.
An the city grew around their vision.

Comment: You haven't provided enough detail. How many angels can dance on the head of a pin? Answer: as many as wanting. One person would build a house, a shed, and a workshop, maybe a barn and corral, in 10 years. Provide enough resources and manpower and you can rebuild Denver in 10 years. It gets easier with more resources. So, what are the limitations? How many people do we have? How much skilled labor? How much access to raw materials and which ones? VTC until enough detail is provided to answer the question in a meaningful way.

Comment: There is no such thing as a self-sufficient mega-city. There is no such thing as a self-sufficient moderately large city. The entire point of cities is that they serve as focal points of trade; they are not self-sufficient, and they are not supposed to be self-sufficient.

Comment: @JBH,
If you expect a detailed breakdown of the 1million population then I'm not sure what are we doing here.
I said the location, they have access to whatever they can get their hands on using current tech. They won't go to Canada or travel overseas. 
But they can range into other states.
They have 1 million people. Many workers and skilled labors.
And they also had people trained.
They might not be able to make a car, but they can fix them.
No new doctors, but again they can cure people...etc.
Anyway what other details are needed?

Comment: @AlexP, 
Yep. 
"self sufficient, as much as possible"
I don't expect them to have a space program and mine their own gold.

Comment: Space programs and gold are not necessities. Food, textiles, leather, construction materials, and fuel are necessities. No large city ever was self sufficient in the basic necessities of life.

Comment: @AlexP
Are you kidding me?
I was denying that they would have that.
Food? I know. I said it.
Yes yes yes.
Those are the basics.
But the question is the extent of buildings.
Will it be a mega city rivaling even those of today, or something more limited as they don't have the massive building capabilities of right now?
Though they have access to skilled labor and a lot of materials, thanks to a large pool of citizen and reclaiming stuff

Comment: Look. The limit of growth of a city was never (and it isn't now) the capacity to build houses. The limit is how much value the city creates, out of which it must buy food, fuel, textiles for its residents, maintain a large workforce to distribute those necessities, pay for the maintenance of the infrastructure etc. What do those million people *do* which is so valuable that it allows them to import food, textiles, leather, wood from long distances, pay for the distribution of water, food, and so on throughout the city, and the maintenance of infrastructure? *This* is the limit of city growth.

Comment: New York City's population was about one million in 1855.  Stack Exchange isn't meant to be a free research service. Will the differences between 1855 and 1865 not be enough to answer your question? A preexisting one-million population would already have considerable buildings and infrastructure. London had 1M in about 1810. Would London 1810-1820 not answer your question? Keep in mind that most of your building goes into housing (babies...).

Comment: And no, you haven't provided enough detail. What was the consequence of the apocalypse? Are these 1M people somehow living in tents? Is there no electricity? No fuel production?  Define ***exactly*** what the starting point is.

Comment: Thanks guys. 
I will work on that. 
@JBH,

Comment: Thanks guys. 
I will work on that. 
@AlexP

Answer (score 3):

I see several big lacks: Vehicle manufacturing, computer manufacturing, and pharmaceuticals/medical equipment.

- Colorado has oil and refining, but lacks the capability to build motors and chassis (and no rubber for tires).
- No way to build computers or replacement components, so you're back to paper for data management.
- Folks will die faster and younger without treatments that we take for granted.

Comment: Obviously.
But there are solutions.
Most of these industries are targeted first.
For example raid a single electronics warehouse and you have enough for the foreseeable future.
Cars are not needed as today.
A single city situation forces people to clump together.
Also because of zombies people live in mini neighbors with minimal contact anyway. 
You have to separate most things anyway.
"pharmaceuticals/medical" is the biggest problem I guess.